# How to select the optimal combination of input variables for supervised learning model?

Tags: machine-learning

While working on a specific assignment, where the goal was to predict the outcome class, I tried several models (neural networks, logistic regression and my custom prediction model) with several combinations of 3 available input variables.

What I found interesting is that the models with two variables outperformed the models with 3 input variables and I would be glad to find some theoretical explanation for such outcome.

Does anyone know, whether there are any sistematic approaches to select the optimal set of input variables? If the input variables are correlated among themself, does this reduce the accuracy of prediction model?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I can give you one possible reason why two variables can sometimes perform better than three.  It could be that a model with three variables is overfitting.  One way to decrease overfitting is to reduce the complexity of the model (eg. using two variables instead of three).  This way the model will generalize better to unseen test data and perform better.  There are ways to see if there is an overfitting problem (eg. comparing training error to test error).

In terms of systematic ways to select the optimal set of input variables, this is called feature selection.  One such approach is to try every single possible combination of input variables and see which combination performs the best.  This can be intractable if you have a large number of possible features so sometimes approximation techniques are used (eg. greedy search).

The impact of correlation among input variables depends on the prediction algorithm that you are using.  Every model has its own inductive bias.  If you are worried about redundancy within your input variables you should try dimensionality reduction (eg. PCA) which will reduce your input variables to only the most informative (i.e. variables that contribute most of the variation within your dataset).

Comment: Thanks @alex! I already diagnosed training and test error and overfitting was not the case. I was wondering whether there are any known approaches for feature selection except trying out all the possible combinations.

Comment: You could try greedy search.  First, find the single best performing feature.  Keep it, then find the best performing feature that combnined with the first produces the best results.  Continue this procedure until your performance stops improving.  This is an approximate approach where you do not need to try all combinations.

Comment: Also, if the model is not overfitting, the difference is probably due to the different inductive biases of the learning algorithms that you are using (different learning algorithms are biased to learning in certain ways).  Also, look up the no-free-lunch theorem which basically states that no learner can solve every problem well.

Comment: This is a nice answer, but the remarks at the end seem inapt: because PCA of the predictors only assesses their correlations, *it has absolutely nothing to do* with their ability to predict. As an artificial but illuminating example, try to predict the *smallest* principal component of a set of Normally-distributed predictors. If you do this with a preliminary PCA and throw out one or more of the smallest components, you will make the predictors independent of the predictand and obliterate your ability to predict altogether!

Comment: I mentioned PCA as a way to reduce redundancy among features.  I don't think I said that it assessed their predictive ability (How could it? It is something you perform on the input features and has nothing to do with the output).

Answer (score 1):

There are many possible systematic approaches to choosing your features. The approaches are often called feature selection, feature reduction, feature extraction, dimensionality reduction etc. etc. (really there are a ridiculous number of names for it). Methods used to choose the features can include greedy approaches, evolutionary algorithms, specialist domain knowledge, more mathematically grounded approaches like PCA, etc. If you have a particular problem in mind then I would suggest reading up on some of the literature and getting an idea of the approach that is most suitable for you. For example, some methods will cause the meaning of your original features to be lost (e.g. through combining features), and if this is not wanted then you may only want to consider selecting a subset of your original features.

As to the theoretical explanation of why fewer features may be better, you might want to have a look at information on the Hughes effect/Hughes phenomenon/peaking paradox (see e.g. [here](http://www.37steps.com/2279/the-peaking-paradox/) or [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality#Machine_learning)). Basically, the performance of a classifier improves with addition of features until a certain (problem dependent) point. After that adding more features can (possibly) be detrimental to the performance of the classifier. Normally this is an issue for higher dimensional problems, but I though it might be of interest to you anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Through Data Mining, we can identify best combinations if large data.
Otherwise go for step wise regression models.